# How can I optimize my Lucence BuildIndex() method to avoid Out of Memory exception?

Tags: c#, indexing, lucene, out-of-memory

I am writing a Lucene index for around 400,000 documents contained under one directory. My buildIndex() method works fine on small subsets of the directory, but of course when I go to build the index for the entire directory, my code throws an out of memory exception. This is my method right now:

```
    public static void BuildIndex()
    {
        FSDirectory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"Z:\Indexer\index"));

        Analyzer analyzer = new SimpleAnalyzer();

        IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);

        foreach(string file in System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(Index.topDirectoryPath, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            indexWriter.AddDocument(TfsDocument.GetLuceneDocument(file));
        }

        indexWriter.Dispose();
    }
```

Note that I am not optimizing for speed, I just want my index to build at a reasonable enough rate without running out of memory. I'm wondering if index.AddDocument or my TfsDocument.GetLucenceDocument() is leaving around stuff in memory? I couldnt' figure out how to implement using() with a Lucence document.

Also, my TfsDocument.GetLuceneDocument() code for reference

```
    public static Document GetLuceneDocument(string path)
    {
        Document document = new Document();

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
           document.Add(new Field("Word", reader.ReadToEnd(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
        }

        document.Add(new Field("Path", path, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

        return document;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Whoever may stumble upon this, I ended up scraping Lucene.Net. After trying to hunt down the leak, I determined that the problem was with Lucene.Net, not my code. Unfortunately, there isn't great support for Lucene.Net. Currently looking for other solutions.